# Android App: reading SD card byte by byte

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-permissions

Is it possible to access the "raw" SD card device from within an Android app to read it byte by byte?

What I mean is something like reading/accessing */dev/sdb* directly (if this would be the SD card device) in some way.

If yes, is there a way to determine the corresponding */dev/**?

Note: I am looking for a solution which does not require root.

Comment: Does nobody have a solution or is this just not possible?

Comment: if you got the solution please share it.

Comment: @SumitUppal still haven´t found a solution for this.